# LaTeX compiles but not pdfLaTeX

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

I have a "project", which has a `main.tex` in `Main` folder, and in `Main` folder, there are subfolders called `tex` and `fig`. In `fig` folder, there is a `logo.eps` file. In `tex` folder, there is a `content.tex` file. In `content.tex`, there is a line

```
\raggedright \includegraphics[height=50px]{logo}
```

When I use `latex` (`Latex` button in `WinEdt`) to compile `main.tex`, it is fine. But if I use `pdflatex` to compile it, I get error message:

```
..
! LaTeX Error: File `logo_amu' not found.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6 ...ght \includegraphics[height=50px]{logo_amu}

? 

Process has been terminated .
```

I would like to use pdfLaTeX to compile my documents. So how do I solve this issue?

Comment: Add `\usepackage{epstopdf}` to your document (assuming that you have a recent tex system).

Comment: Please make sure to check for existing questions before posting a new question. There are several possible duplicates for this question and they’re not too hard to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDFTeX does not interpret PostScript files. So you should transform your *.EPS file onto *.PDF. You can use, e.g., `epstopdf` package.

Comment: IMHO, a better way is to convert EPS graphics to PDF in advance. Just run `epstopdf logo_amu.eps` in command line. To convert all EPS files in current folder run `for %f in (*.eps) do epstopdf %f`.